# Limit maintenance view output based on authorization

Tags: authorization, abap, sap-basis, sap-data-dictionary

How can i limit on table maintenance fetching data base on authorization?

For instance the user only can view plant/storage location based on the authorization object because sometimes the user gets confused of too many plants are irrelevant for him.

[image: Maintenance view]

Answer (score 6):

In the table maintenance generator for your table or view, choose `Environment -> Modification -> Events` from the menu.

Here you have the option to extend the logic of the table maintenance generator at particular points during the execution.

You are able to define your own logic; one promising event might be 'AA' (Instead of the standard data read routine). You should be able to change the logic for reading data to perform a custom authority check that will allow users to see only records for which they have access.

Here is a document on SDN relating to the topic of using the table maintenance events: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/TABLE+MAINTENANCE+GENERATOR+and+ITS+EVENTS